# Grease pencil "Failed to find" materials with line art modifier on a blank stroke with Blender 3.1

Tags: grease-pencil

**Update**, it is not a bug.

I had changed *Preferences->Editing->Objects->New Objects->Link Materials* To: *Object Data* to just plain *Object*.

But, "Modifiers only affect the Data, so it's understandable not to use Object materials in modifiers."

---

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or if I should report a bug. Be aware that the only way I have been able to get Blender working right again is to **reload the default preferences.**

1. Add a blank grease pencil stroke to the default scene.
2. Add a 'Line art' modifier to the stroke.
3. Click on the Material slot of the line art modifier and then click on the blank pop up where a black material should be and you should get a Failed to find '' error.
   [image]

With Blender 3.0.1 I get a default black material for the blank stroke.

Should I just report this as a bug?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Did you by any chance modify the startup file ?

Comment: It first happened after I made some changes with the startup file. But to check it out I set the startup file back to default and went from there. I could find anything about the problem online so I'll try filing a bug report.

Comment: Sorry I did not get if reverting to default fixed the problem

Comment: I didn't explain right. If you don't run File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings the grease pencil line art modifier won't work anymore.  If you add a stroke or suzanne grease pencil object the line modifier will find the materials for the objects and you can continue on.                                        https://developer.blender.org/T96349

Comment: Alright makes sense thanks for the bug report. Cheers

Comment: It was not a bug, I had changed Preferences->Editing->Objects->New Objects->Object Data to just plain "Object". But, "Modifiers only affect the Data, so it's understandable not to use Object materials in modifiers."